# Android chat app testing

Tags: android, robotium, robolectric, android-testing

Consider a simple chat app, you can send and receive text messages.
I need to perform some black box testing, but have no idea how to co-ordinate two clients.

For example:

Let's assume that the test is to check if `user1` can sent a message to `user2`. Here, I can make `user1` send message using [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) but how to assert if `user2` (i.e. on other device/emulator) has received the text.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way for something like this is to do two tests, one for each case. So with only one device/emulator, you write a test that verifies the correct behaviour when a message gets sent and another test for when a message gets received. You only need one device/emulator.

The kind of test you are describing is technically possible, but you need to build out quite a bit to make it happen, as robotium by itself will not be enough for this. Not sure it's worth it.